# error in shell script in syntax

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
 for f in `ls *.png`
  do
convert $f -fill gray(50%) -opaque black ./background_change/$f
  done
  for f in `ls *.PNG`
   do
  convert $f -fill gray(50%) -opaque black ./background_change/$f
  done
```

For the above mentioned shell script I get an error saying :

```
[gsamanth@cngfile Acsady]$ sh background_change.sh 
'ackground_change.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'ackground_change.sh: line 3: `do
[gsamanth@cngfile Acsady]$
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Those error messages show your script has carriage returns. Use `dos2unix` on your script file.

Answer (score 1):

Tips:

- [Don't parse LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You'll run in to problems more often than you expect.  Process files using a `for` loop, or with the `find` command.
- Always quote your variables.  Your script has: `convert $f -file ...`.  What happens if a filename contains a space followed by a hyphen?

```sh
 #!/bin/sh

 for f in *.png *.PNG; do
     convert "$f" -fill "gray(50%)" -opaque black background_change/"$f"
 done
```

Note that you want quotes around your fill parameter, because otherwise the shell will interpret the brackets instead of passing them as an option.  You could also achieve this by escaping the brackets with backslashes (i.e. `gray\(50%\)`).  But quotes are a bit safer, as they'll also save you from other characters that you might not know to escape.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semi-colon before the `do` clause:

```
for f in `ls *.png`; do
                   ^
                   +- here
```

You can also use wildcards in the shell script itself, no need to call `ls`. All in all, your script should be

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.png *.PNG; do
    convert $f -fill gray(50%) -opaque black ./background_change/$f
done
```

Comment: @GopalSamant Oh yes it does. You may have other errors as well.

Comment: I am not much familiar to writing shell scripts. Is it necessary that we do not have any extra whitespaces in the script?

Comment: @GopalSamant No, it isn't. But perhaps if you specified what exactly "does not work" mean, we could **actually** help.

Comment: `[gsamanth@cngfile Acsady]$ sh background_change.sh 
'ackground_change.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `
'ackground_change.sh: line 2: `for f in *.png;
[gsamanth@cngfile Acsady]$ 
`

Comment: @GopalSamant - If you have additional data to clarify your question, you should [add it to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13347051/edit).  Comments are not a good place for formatted code, and your question should be self-contained, not relying on comments on other people's answers.

Comment: @H2CO3: he does *not* need a semicolon before the `do` if the `do` is on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for f in `ls *.PNG`; do
```

or (better still)

```
for f in *.PNG; do
```

to avoid the excessive `ls` invocation (unless you later want to make use of some `ls` facility like sorting - I suspect not though)

Comment: Parsing ls is never a good idea.  Even if it works in some cases, recommending it as a solution to someone who is learning will increase the chance that they'll use this solution for some *other* problem for which it is dangerous.  "This is how you shoot yourself in the foot!"

Comment: Well, that's why I marked it as 'better still' although perhaps I should have been more explicit

Comment: Basic ls exposes the user to filenames that have spaces or other characters in them.  Feeding the ls output to a line-by-line read function ensures handling of only 1 filename at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The ls command can provide different results depending on your environment and settings.  I will not go into what those are here.

For that reason, it is best to feed the output of **ls** as a stream to a separate "**while**" (*or depending on complexity, **awk***) loop, which would then

1. read each line,
2. evaluate each line for "preparation" or "conditioning" pre-processing before
3. running the desired
   command.

Since undesirable conditions (space or special characters in file names) are unavoidable (unless you have a process which prevents such filenames from being created in the first place), it is a good preventative first measure to always put double-quotes around any variable which involves a filename of unknown format, such as

`"/thisdir/anotherdir/${filename}"` .

This example puts those principles in action:

```
START=`pwd`
rm -f ${START}/rename.EXCEPTIONS.txt

EVALdir="${HOME}/Downloads"
cd ${EVALdir}

ls | while read line
do
     if [ -z "${line}" ] ; then break ; fi
     newname=`echo "${line}" | sed 's+\ +_+g' `
     echo "\n\t Rename '${line}' to '${newname}' ? [y|N] => \c"
     read ans ; if [ -z "${ans}" ] ; then ans="N" ; fi
     case ${ans} in
         y* | Y* )  mv -v "${line}" "${newname}" ;
         * ) echo "IGNORED|${line}|" >&2 ;;
     esac 2>${START}/rename.EXCEPTIONS.txt
done
```

Since the actions of saving of web page or file to disk is a frequent cause of such filename conditions, it is a good practice to have a periodic scan of your entire system (on only those parts to which users can save files to) to detect the offending conditions or characters and flag such instances in an a report for corrective action, to minimize

- the number of instances where lack of coding for such conditions can
  lead to undesirable outcome, and
- the multiple instances required to
  incorporate the necessary special coding to correctly handle such
  instances.